# SSH connection to the AWS EC2 freezes on connecting or on building

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I've set up my server on EC2 and successfully logged into it through SSH several times. But after some time it started freezing the console. For example, when I try to connect to it, it simply freezes at that step or sometimes it succeeds and then when I try to run a compiler (TypeScript, so it's really not that heavy on the resources) it freezes.

When I say "freeze" I mean it gets stuck at that step for a very long time. Pressing any key is also heavily throttled. I'm able to exit it with Ctrl + C, but trying again results in the same.

I've looked at the monitoring graphs on the AWS console and they all look fine to me, nothing unusual on any of the resources.

I've contacted the AWS support but no luck from that. :/

Comment: seems me some issues with your network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Consider switching to a larger instance, it may be because of memory usage.
- Examine the OS logs in `/var/log/*`. This may contain some clues about the problem
- If it still persist try **restarting** your instance a couple of times.
- Also check your network connectivity.

Comment: Restarting the instance finally helped me, it seems to work fine now. Thank you!